# Touchable Opacity messes up width in row container

Tags: react-native, mobile-application, touchableopacity

I'm trying to make these two Card components appear next to each other in a row as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW0ow.png) which seems to work when I wrap the component in a `View`, but appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvzzp.png) with a bunch of unnecessary space in between when I try it with a `TouchableOpacity`.

Here is my code for the Card component (currently with `TouchableOpacity` on and the `View` wrapper commented out):

```
  export const NavCard = ({
  title,
  height = 200,
  onPress = null,
  background = null,
}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={onPress}
      style={[
        { height: height },
        background ? styles.cardImage : styles.noImage,
      ]}
    >
      {/* <View
        style={[
          { height: height },
          background ? styles.cardImage : styles.noImage,
        ]}
      > */}
      <Image
        source={background}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{
          height: height,
          width: "100%",
          borderRadius: 15,
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
        }}
      />
      <View style={{ padding: 15 }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Image
          style={styles.arrow}
          source={require("../assets/arrow-right.png")}
        />
      </View>
      {/* </View> */}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardImage: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    margin: "2%",
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
  noImage: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    margin: "2%",
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: "#333436",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#E4E5EA",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 4,
  },
  arrow: {
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 22,
    right: 20,
  },
});
```

Here is the code for the screen:

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
        <NavCard
          title="Map"
          height={180}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Map")}
          background={require("../assets/pvdx1.png")}
        ></NavCard>
        <NavCard
          title="CAD"
          height={180}
          background={require("../assets/pvdx1.png")}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CADScreen")}
        ></NavCard>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    padding: 4,
    flex: 1,
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  body: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#E4E5EA",
  },
});

export default HomeScreen
```

Does anyone know why it's messing up the width of both components if the styles of the `View` and `TouchableOpacity` are exactly the same? I'm using React Native.

**Edit**: Have updated to use `Image` instead of `ImageBackground` (code now reflects this), but the result is the same.

Comment: Please check after remove `justifyContent: "space-between"` in HomeScreen. let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: @JohnOcean This just gets rid of the space in between the two cards and presses them together aligned at the right. I'm trying to get it to have the same behavior as when I use <View> where there is space in between, but both cards exand to fill up the full width (aside from margins in between)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue: I was importing `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native-gesture-handler` instead of `react-native`. Changed it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in your `<ImageBackground />` , Because I replaced that with native `<Image />` and it's working. here is how my Image looks, you can compare with your code:

```
<Image
        style={{
          height: height,
          borderRadius: 15,
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          width: "100%"
        }}
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={{ uri: "https://via.placeholder.com/250x150" }}
      />
```

[Here you can check the working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-hooks-9fmyz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I've changed my `ImageBackground` into exactly the above, but it still ends up as very far apart.

Comment: @sophosn well in the link that I attached, I'm using your exact code. did you check the link?

Comment: yes, I actually also commented out all of my other code to just include the rowContainer and the NavCards on that screen, but it still is showing up with a giant space in the middle.

Comment: I also copied and pasted your code exactly, but it has the same result. Could the problem be somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

for me i had to also set the width on the TouchableOpacity (and the view within)

```
 <TouchableOpacity
    style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}
```